# angular.io material mat-slide-toggle doesn't work on android chrome

Tags: android, angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material2

I am using a mat-slide-toggle on the angular web app.

```
<mat-slide-toggle [checked]="pickCache.getAutoPack()" (change)="onChangeAutoPack($event)">Auto Pack</mat-slide-toggle>
```

It displays fine on the desktop chrome browser.

[image: mat-slide-toggle on desktop chrome browser]

However, when I deploy to the web server and open from my Nexus 5X smart phone in the chrome browser app, it looks horrible.

[image: mat-slide-toggle on android chrome browser]

Why?

Comment: There seems to be no theme

Comment: @Faisal I think you are right.  It's not the android browser.  I get the same behavior when I hit the testing server from the desktop browser.  So, it looks correct on localhost (my desktop web server), but upon deploy to server, it looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It had nothing to do with the Android Chrome browser.  Thanks to @Faisal for the hint above.  My stylesheet to the css link had an absolute reference.

So, on localhost, the reference was

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/deeppurple-amber.css">
```

However, when I deployed to an intranet url, it included a virtual directory folder name, which broke the absolute url reference.

Solution was to make relative as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/deeppurple-amber.css">
```